# How can I create large ASCII text from a string?

Tags: html, text

Given a string, for example 'imgur', how can I generate large ASCII text like the following? Thanks.

```
   _
  (_)
   _ _ __ ___   __ _ _   _ _ __
  | | '_ ` _ \ / _` | | | | '__|
  | | | | | | | (_| | |_| | |
  |_|_| |_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|
                __/ |
               |___/
```

Comment: Looks like you just did it (I have no idea what you are asking for. I suggest you provide more context. 6 words is hardly enough to describe a problem.)

Comment: what did you tried for this ?

Comment: just more know, for my console :D

Comment: could you specify how you want to go about it? Like you wanted to use HTML how and where it would be generated and used? what is the line of thought?

Comment: *"for my console"* Now it makes even less sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ASCII text generator like FIGlet which uses FIGlet fonts. TOIlet is like FIGlet and can use FIGlet fonts but as additional capabilities including Unicode handling, colour fonts, filters and various export formats. Specific logos may need to be created as their own font.

Here are some links:

- FIGlet: http://www.figlet.org/
- TOIlet: https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/toilet/
- FIGlet fonts: http://www.figlet.org/fontdb.cgi
- FIGlet web demo: http://www.kammerl.de/ascii/AsciiSignature.php